# Flutter: Change image of a column in a grid view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tic-tac-toe

I'm relatively new to flutter app development. I'm trying to build a simple Tic Tac Toe game. I have added a GridView to simulate a 3 x 3 grid. For now, each column is a circle shape icon. I want to change this to either "X" or "O" based on player's turn. How can I place the specific image in a specific column after identifying whose turn is it?

This is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container variable = Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );

    if (headline == '') {
      headline = "Home Page";
    }
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return (Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(authUser.currentUser.email),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  'Player 1 (0 - 0) Player 2',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 22),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index == 1 || index == 3 || index == 5 || index == 7) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => onClickOdd(context, index),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              variable = (Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                              ));
                            },
                            child: variable),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => onClickEven(context, index),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              variable = (Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                              ));
                            },
                            child: variable),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  itemCount: 9,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 65,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 50, left: 130, right: 130, bottom: 120),
                child: ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 60,
                  height: 100,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Button',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      return (Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(authUser.currentUser.email),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.blue[100],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.8),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => onClickEven(context, index),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[400],
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        )),
                    itemCount: 9,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }
```

P.S: Sorry is you find part of the code duplicate, I'm trying to design different layout based on device's orientation.

This is the output I'm getting:
[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfhTX.png)

Thanks!

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfhTX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a logic here the logic isto make it even odd situation, suppose if the index is 0 its means it even then put here 0 , if 1 then then number is odd put here x.

Comment: Yeah I got that. I already identified whose turn is it. But how can I actually place the "X" or "O" image in that specific column. If you can provide a snippet that would be great.

Comment: check the index then use the logic check its even or odd then use  stack or direct image for your 0 or X

Comment: itemBuilder: (context, index) {  if(index == odd ) {return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => onClick(context, index),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[400],
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        )),}else {}}

Comment: Something like that i don't have the situation to code right now sorry  ,you can take it as idea and implement it by own .thanks

Comment: I updated the code as you said but I'm still unable to achieve the desired result. Initially, I want to display the same image (or empty grid), then if a user click specific image, only that is updated. I want to change the image in onClickEven and onClickOdd function. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: use Inkwell in the image then it will work

Comment: Inkwell( onTab: () => do your staff,child: Image())

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a novice in Flutter. I tried doing it (updated the code, but on clicking (gesture is detected) image colour is not changing). Can you please provide a snippet that I can use? That will be very helpful. Thank you very much. – Ashar 13 mins ago     Delete

Comment: Container(color:Colors.red,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),

Comment: Use this instead use color in the box decoration